# Как увеличить размер в turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle

```py
from turtle import*
tracer(0); left(90); down(); right(315)
for _ in range(7): forward(16*20); right(45); forward(8*20); right(135)
up()
for x in range(-15,15):
    for y in range(0,25):
        setpos(x*20,y*20)
        dot(3,"red")
update()
```

На картинке сложно разглядеть точки, их позицию, лежат ли они на линиях или нет - как исправить?
[image: Картинка, на которой сложно подсчитать количество точек и их расположение (лежат ли на линиях или нет)]

Comment: Замените `dot(3, "red")` на `dot(5, "red")`

Answer (score 0):

Для изменения ширины пера черепашки в пикселях можно применить команду `turtle.pensize()`. Аргумент команды – целое число, задаёт ширину пера.